# OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code flow using javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, token, keycloak

I am developing a simple html5 frontend application that retrieves an OAuth2.0 access token from a generic OAuth 2.0 provider (e.g. Keycloak and alike). Assuming the user has previously created a client and user on the authentication server (e.g. Keycloak) he then provides the following parameters on my web page:

- Authorization URL
- Access token URL
- Client ID
- Client secret

Sort of a **Postman OAuth2.0** client:
[image]

Note: ClientId and Client secret are not saved anywhere, they are provided by the user.

**My question is:** 
Is there any javascript library to achieve such behaviour (Postman)?

Comment: I agree with @Rubysmith, the authorization code grant type is not designed for JS application. You must use the implicit grant type

Comment: @FlorentMorselli I know, but the purpose of this frontend app is to test the Authorization Code Flow!

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `Implicit Grant Flow` and not the `Authorization Code Flow` in OAuth2 for client side JavaScript applications where one cannot safely keep secrets inside the application.

[Implicit Grant Flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#page-26)

Comment: The secrets are not saved anywhere as they are provided by the user via a web form. As an aside, it doesn't answer the original question, which was about the js library.

Comment: As of 2019, it is recommended for SPAs to use Code flow with PKCE extension and without client secret. So the question actually makes sense now, and this answer is outdated.

Comment: Perhaps you have misunderstood my original intent. I just wanted to mimic Postman's behavior in my own web app. This test app doesn't go to production.